# How to bind a __device__ array (not cudaArray) to a 3D texture in CUDA

Tags: cuda

I have an array:

```
__device__ float4 data[64];
```

Now I hope to bind this array to a 3D texture, how could I do that?

I only know how to bind cudaArray to 3D texture. Should I copy the data[64] array to host memory, then copy that memory to a cudaArray? Or is there any way to directly copy this array to a cudaArray?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can only bind 3D-cudaArrays to 3D textures. You can copy normal device memory to a cudaArray using `cudaMemcpy3D(const struct cudaMemcpy3DParms *p);` directly without the need to go over host. But on the other hand, why do you use a normal flat array at all? If you need to write to your array, you might want have a look at cuda surfaces and avoid the copying.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I haven't used cuda surface before. I'm going to take a look at it.